# Counting the number of occurrences of all groupings (consecutive occurrences of the same number) in a list

Tags: counting

If the variable "digits" contains a sequence of numbers how to count how many times each grouping of a number occurs? For instance, for number $1$ how many times it occurs once consequitivly $(...,1,...)$ how many times twice consecutively $(...,1,1,...)$, so on until all of the consecutive occurrences it has in the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SequenceCases` followed by `Tally` or `Counts`:

```
digits = {0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1};
Counts@SequenceCases[digits, l : {1 ..} :> Length[l]]
```

> `<|2 -> 2, 1 -> 1, 3 -> 1|>`

Before `SequenceCases` existed, contiguous sequences might have been detected like this:

```
Counts@Cases[Split[digits], l : {1 ..} :> Length[l]]
```

> `<|2 -> 2, 1 -> 1, 3 -> 1|>`